# How to make monster move smoothly in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

```
self.dir = random.randint(1,4)
amount = 20 
if self.dir == 1: 
    self.direction = 'forwards'
    dist = 0
    while dist < amount: 
        self.rect.y += 1
        dist += 1
```

This is what I have right now. However, the monster is still just jumping pixels instead of going one pixel at a time. I think this is because the move function for the monster is being called in the main function, which is set to clock.tick(60). Does anyone know what I could do to fix this?

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal, runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? It looks like you need to remove the `while dist < amount:` loop and just move the object a few pixels (the desired speed) every frame.

Comment: when you run `while dist < amount: self.rect.y += 1` then it changes value `self.rect.y` but it doesn't return to mainloop to redraw moster after every pixel. It does the same as `self.rect.y += amount`

Comment: The reason I have the while loop is because I only want the monster to change direction after it has gone a good amount of distance. I don't want it to go a few pixels and then change direction because the move function was called again